# Fourier transform an expression to obtain a distribution?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have this expression for the correlation function for a rigid rotating molecule:

$G(\tau) = 4 \pi  \int \omega ^2 P_2[\cos (\omega \tau)] P(\omega) \, \mathrm{d}\omega \quad [1]$

where $P_2$ is a second order Legendre polynomial, and $P(\omega)$ is some distribution function.

and they say "$P(\omega)$ can be solved either by a Fourier transform of Eg. 1 or by choosing an appropriate model for $P(\omega)$"

An example of this 'done' in the book is:

[image: fft]

They say "(bottom graph) Angular velocity distribution functional $P(\omega)$ obtained from a Fourier Transform of $G(\tau)$ (the top graph)"

I am quite confused how I go about obtaining this distribution via a Fourier transform. I tried a few functions in mathematica but got no where. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: I think the idea is to use orthogonality of Legendre Polynomials:

Comment: It you write $$P(\omega)=\sum_n P_n(\omega) a_n$$ and $$G(\tau)=\sum_n P_n(\tau) b_n$$ and plug this into (1), integrate over $\tau$ you will get a relationship between $a_n$ and $b_n$ ?

Comment: Hmm, I actually have some data of G(t), it is just a decaying exponential. I can take an FFT of it but it just looks very noisy. I have edited a screenshot from the book that shows their data + result of the distribution from the Fourier Transform.